# Chromecast doesn't want to work with VLC 3.0.1

Tags: xubuntu, vlc, chromecast

I'm trying to make VLC + ChromeCast work on my computer (Xubuntu - 16.04.4 LTS).

I deleted my PPA VLC to install the new 3.0.1 VLC version as a snap.

VLC finds my ChromeCast, and when I click on it, it connects. That's perfect (I have some pings going on in the logs).

BUT: when I try to cast something, I have the loading bar on my chromecast, over and over, and then, after a while, it stops.

Does anyone have any idea of the reason it doesn't work, and how I can make it work?

It seems to "try to finds some candidates" or something...

Comment: Your pastebin link is dead. Did you resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem and found that the issue was the Ubuntu firewall. I disabled it and all works.

Comment: Could you add some detail about what exactly you did? Also, this seems like a bit of a heavy-handed solution to me.  Mightn't there be some way to allow only whatever was needed?

Comment: @KarlRichter it is an attempt to answer. Not a 'having the same problem' post. Just needs to be explained a bit better ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it ! i just re-installed it, and try without the firewall (sudo ufw disable) and it works Perfectly ! thanks again !